# Rotating table header when using twitter bootstrap tables

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have managed to to rotate the header of a column on a table as such I am still getting the following problem:

[image]

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```
  .box_rotate 
            {
                 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
                   -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
              -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
                         filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);  /* IE6,IE7 */
                     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)"; /* IE8 */
            }

<table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr style="height:5%;"><th style="width:2.5%">#</th><th style="width:25%;">Task</th><th>Progress</th><th><div class="box_rotate" style="height:10%;">Start Time</div></th><th>End Time</th><th style="width:2.5%">1</th><th style="width:2.5%">2</th><th style="width:2.5%">3</th><th style="width:2.5%">4</th><th style="width:2.5%">5</th><th style="width:2.5%">6</th><th style="width:2.5%">7</th><th style="width:2.5%">8</th><th style="width:2.5%">9</th><th style="width:2.5%">10</th></tr>
        </table>
```

I've tried trying to change the row and columns height to see if the words would fit into the column but I haven't had any luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use a pseudo element and vertical-padding in % to force to draw a square.
 see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin-top 
basicly:

```
element:before {
content:'';
padding:50% 0;
}
```

will take width of element as a reference to calculate vertical `padding` if  % . here 50% x 2 = 100% of element's `width`

you can then apply the `transform:rotate(xxdeg)` and set it with `transform-origin`.
your code can become for younger browser :

```
.box_rotate /* if more tha one line, content should be wrap in a div displayed as inline-boxe */
{
  vertical-align:middle;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
  filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);  /* IE6,IE7 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)"; /* IE8 */
  transform-origin:    center;

}
.box_rotate:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;/* allow to vertical-center a box aside */
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:0 -0.25em;
  padding-top:100%;
}
table, th {
  border:solid;
}
```

This works with little content , it seems okay for a  short  `<th>` title.

IE6 will need an extra element instead of pseudo. I did not look after IE behaviors. but you have the writing-mode, wich in my opinion is more like what you need. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx